# How to embed a React starterkit app into legacy Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, react-starter-kit

I have a React app based on the starterkit of Erik Rasmussen from [here](https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example).

The app works pretty well, using React Router and Redux.

Since my Rails app is pretty old, the idea to embed the application, is to have a separate controller where the `index` action renders an iFrame, which itself loads it's content from the same controllers `show` action.

Therefore I can stick with my Rails app's layout, and have the React apps markup rendered w/o any changes.

After I transpiled the app via

`$> npm run build`

I copy the main-***.js and main-***.css files into the Rails app, so they can be delivered from there.

Afterwards I start the React app via:

`$> npm run start`

and request the starting page via curl. The curl output goes into my `show` erb template. Inside I change the URL's where the main JS and CSS is loaded from.

When I request my `index` page now, the iFrame loads it's content, the app seems to initialize, but does not work at all. I see rendered content, but clicking on links leads to Rails routing errors. So the clicks seem not to be intercepted by React.

I tried to track execution down, and ended up debugging the code in `client.js`. It seems like, `ReactDOM.render` receives proper arguments, meaning, there is a proper looking component to render, a store, and even the destination element.

Currently I get the following error in the console:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: _classCallCheck is not defined`

I am using a slightly oder version of the starterkit, which embeds initial data into the markup, but I was not able to figure out, why the _classCallCheck works in the React app, but stops working, when embedded into Rails.

Even the most recent version of the starterkit does not work either. In that case I do not get any error at all, but have the same behavior.

Due to the old Rails version I can not use the React Gem, and I need some of the functionality the starterkit provides out of the box, so changing this one, is no option either.

Any hints?

Comment: Are you sure this is a wise path? If you have a legacy Rails which is on a very old version of rails you should prioritise upgrading the app for security reasons before adding features. Additionally if the goal is to build a Single Page Application you might not need the overhead of the Rails server to serve the application. Instead you simply need a build toolchain and a server which can serve static files. You can then create a API in Rails which your SPA uses as a backend.

Comment: Thx @max for the input. Unfortunately it is not helpful, because I am aware of the downsides and also know, what options there are. Upgrading the legacy Rails app is not an option. The SPA needs to be integrated, since the functionality can not be implemented otherwise with the current resources. Thx for your input anyway.